# Sign of current through a voltage source

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current-measurement

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQWQn0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am a total newbie to circuits, so please forgive my naivety. My question is the following:

When I simulate the above circuit in LTspice, the current across the voltage source is shown to be negative (-.05). That means in this case they mark the current coming out of the the positive terminal of the battery as negative. Is that just a convention or is there some logic behind it? If it's a convention, is that the general standard?

Comment: According to Kirchhoff's current law, the sum of currents flowing into a node equals the sum of all currents flowing out of it. To make it a more clear question, I think it is wise to add arrows and values for each current you're measuring.

Comment: @jippie I'm also new to to CircuitLab (this is the first circuit I drew there).. let me see how I can put labels. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'positive' current is defined as flow from a higher potential to lower potential. You should see that for the resistor in your simulator. Within the voltage source however, the current flows from the negative terminal (lower potential) towards positive terminal (higher potential). Hence the negative sign.

Comment: Which just to be confusing is the opposite direction to the way that electrons flow :)

Answer (score 3):

> the current across the voltage source is shown to be negative (-.05)

Before getting into the meat of your question, we normally say that current flows "through" a device, not a "across' it.

> That means in this case they mark the current coming out of the the positive terminal of the battery as negative. Is that just a convention or is there some logic behind it?

This is the [passive current convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention). It is widely used (Wikipedia says "universally") in electrical engineering.

If you use this convention consistently, then when you calculate the power \$P\$ associated with the component, you will always know what the sign of \$P\$ means.
If you calculate

$$P=IV$$

with the signs defined by the passive current convention, then a positive \$P\$ means that the component is receiving power from the rest of the circuit, and a negative \$P\$ means that the component is delivering power to the rest of the circuit. Therefore when we use voltage sources to deliver power to the circuit, we expect the current through the source to have a negative sign.

> If it's a convention, is that the general standard?

This is the most common standard, in my experience, when somebody actually thinks about using a standard convention to define the current direction.

It's also common, at least in one-off calculations, to simply do things *ad hoc*, and assign the sign of currents arbitrarily or according to what the engineer thinks will end up giving positive values in the solution. But that doesn't really apply to the designers of LTSpice, who had to choose a convention for any circuit a user might come up with.

Comment: Wow. I can't thank you enough for the super comprehensive answer! Thank you also for touching on the convention with regard to power. Things are clearer to me now.

Answer (score 0):

In simulation normally positive current is one that flows into a pin, while negative flows out of it. So if you have negative value, check if you use the right pin of your source.

Comment: Thanks. I notice that in case of resistor. Flipping it makes the current through it positive or negative. But how can that apply to a battery? Doesn't a battery already have in-ambiguous positive and negative terminals?

Comment: Sure. But so does the "current probe".

Comment: Ah I think I get your point. You're saying the sign might depend on how we position our current measuring instrument. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Again, it assumes that the current flows out of the pin, so if in fact it flows into it, the sign flips.

Comment: Hmm. When you say in and out of the pin, I assume you mean a particular terminal (marked 'positive' or something like that), as the current flowing in any pin will also have to flow out of it somewhere?

Comment: Let's say it's from component to wire.

Comment: Ah.. that's clearer.I've upvoted your helpful answer but seems like it will only reflect when I attain certain credibility myself.  So for the moment I must say thank you so much for your time and help!